# I need to convert something like "1 hour 9 mins" to seconds in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex, google-maps, time

I am writing an online navigation app based on Google's API and need to time the text-to-speech and popups.

Here is my situation: I'm getting strings like "At junction 15, exit onto M4 toward London (109 mi, 1 hour 41 mins)" and need to extract the "1 hour 41 mins" part and convert it into seconds, which Google tells me is 6060 seconds. Can anyone help with this?

I also need to extract the "109 mi" part (which could be "0.3 mi", or "16 ft"). I have no idea how I'd go about doing that. I can do the Ajax and API stuff, and I just need the distance and time in seconds (for JavaScript's setTimeout).

Comment: Oh, just to note I could accept a JavaScript solution, as I will be passing the strings via AJAX (I need to take the "109 mi" part and the "1 hour 41 mins" part out, discard the leftovers of that bit and pass the "At junction 15, exit onto M4 towards London" bit separately (I will use JSON, and basically I'll give the bits [text, distance, time] separately via PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting the data with JavaScript you can use something like `string.match(/\((\d+) mi, (.*)\)/)` where `string` is the string you get back.

This will get you an array with [1] with `119` and [2] with `1 hour 41 min` for that case. Then you can ajax it to the server and do what you need doing.

**Perhaps a better regex would be** `string.match(/\((\d+) (mi|ft), (.*)\)$/)`, and now you know if the first number is *mi* or *ft*.

Comment: How do I take the data out of string?

Comment: I'd need the mi part as well, also it could be ft. But thanks!

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null fiddle.jshell.net/:23
window.onload when I replace mi with ft

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't look up :P

Comment: One last thing: how do I take the (109 mi...) part out of string? @Guy

Answer (score 2):

By PHP you can convert a string to seconds like this:

```
strtotime("1 hour 9 minutes") - time();
```

Comment: How would I extract it from the string?

Comment: Get whatever comes in the brackets () and split it by ",".

Comment: write regullar expression which will return $string in brackets, then $array = explode ("," $string); Your $array[1] will be "1 hour 9 minutes".

Comment: How do I get what's in the brackets and take the leftovers out? (I can do explode() on it, I just need the content taken out, as in moved.

Comment: I suck at regexes. I can't do them.

Comment: preg_match('/\(([^\)]*)\)/', $yourString, $matches);

Comment: @VaheShadunts Does that take the string out?

Comment: $matches is Array, do the var_dump() you'll see

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it including using a function based on stripos(x,y) & substr(x,y) only, plus a trim thing for removing the whitespaces...

Here's the function:

```
function extract_unit($string, $start, $end)
{
    $pos = stripos($string, $start);
    $str = substr($string, $pos);
    $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));
    $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);
    $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);
    $unit = trim($str_three);
    return $unit;
}
```

Read more [here](http://www.bitrepository.com/extract-content-between-two-delimiters-with-php.html).

Example of use in your case:

```
$text = '1 hour 9 mins';
$hours = (int)extract_unit($text, '', 'hour'); // Returns 1
$mins = (int)extract_unit($text, 'hour', 'mins'); // Returns 9
$secs = ($hours*3600) + ($mins*60); // Returns 4140
```